# MS-Access VB script convert string to Date

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

can you advice if I can convert that string into Date in my MS Access db, which I assume uses VB. I got this CustNum created during tx and looks like takes a TimeStamp which I want to use for my date calculation, looks like I need do some parsing, hyphen replacement before converting with CDate, I  tried couple of ways and failed so far. Ultimately I want to use this value to calculate how much time passed.

```
    CustNum = '2018-05-14-154540'
    CDate([CustNum]     ##.... something like this
## to be used in query builder as 
    DaysPassed: CDate([CustNum]) - Now()
```

Comment: If that is your standard format try `CDATE(LEFT(CustNum,10))`. Not 100% sure `CDate` will parse that but it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse that bad boy a bit first to make it conform to what MSAccess is expecting. If CustNum's format changes then you'll need to write a case statement to deal with each format, but essentially:

```
CustNum = Left(CustNum, 10) & " " & Mid(CustNum,12,2) & ":" &_ 
Mid(CustNum,14,2) & ":" & Mid(CustNum,16,2)
CustNum = CDATE(CustNum)
DaysPassed = DateDiff("d",CustNum, Now()) 'gives the difference in Days
HoursPassed = DateDiff("h",CustNum,Now())  'gives the difference in hours
MinsPassed = DateDiff("n",CustNum,Now())  'gives the difference in minutes
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do some fancy parsing to retrieve the date and time:

```
TimeStamp = CDate(Left(CustNum, 10) & Format(CustNum, " !@@:@@:@@"))
```

You can then use the function below to display the time used:

```
TimeSpent = FormatHourMinuteDiff(TimeStampStart, TimeStampEnd)
```

The function:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinuteDiff( _
  ByVal datTimeStart As Date, _
  ByVal datTimeEnd As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of difference
' between datTimeStart and datTimeEnd converted to
' hours and minutes as a signed formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTimeStart: #10:03#
'   datTimeEnd  : #20:01#
'   returns     : 9:58
'
'   datTimeStart: #22:13#
'   datTimeEnd  : #3:45#
'   returns     : -18:28
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Const cintMinutesHour As Integer = 60

  Dim lngMinutes    As Long
  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  lngMinutes = DateDiff("n", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)
  strHour = CStr(lngMinutes \ cintMinutesHour)
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Abs(lngMinutes) Mod cintMinutesHour), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinuteDiff = strHourMinute

End Function
```